# clipping a UIImage as per a polygon

Tags: iphone, uiimage, quartz-2d

How can I let the user of my iphone app to clip a UIImage by a dynamically generated CGPath. Basically I display a rectangle overlaid on a UIImageView and the user can move the 4 corners of the rectangle to get a polygon with 4 sides. The rectangle is not filled so you see four lines overlaid on an image.

The user should be able to clip out whatever is outside the 4 lines.

Any help or pointers is much appreciated.

Comment: what is your question? Do you need help for what? Drawing the rectangle?

Comment: I need help to display a clipped UIImage. The rectangle is drawn fine. I also get a CGPath correctly each time when the user moves any of the 4 ends of the rectangle. How can I use this to clip the background UIImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the CGPath, you just have to use `CGContextAddPath` and `CGContextClip`, and after that you can draw your UIImage on that context.
If you just want to display the clipped image, that context could be the current context in the `DrawRect` method of your view.
If you actually want to have the clipped image data, the context would probably be a `CGBitmapContext`, something like this:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

size_t bytesPerPixel = 1;
size_t bytesPerRow = bmpWidth * bytesPerPixel;
size_t bmpDataSize = ( bytesPerRow * bmpHeight);

unsigned char *bmpData = malloc(bmpDataSize);
memset(bmpData, 0, bmpDataSize);

CGContextRef bmpCtx = CGBitmapContextCreate(bmpData, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
```

(the code example is for a grey scale bitmap because I had that code ready, but it's not hard to figure out what has to be changed for an RGB bitmap.)

then to actually draw the clipped image to the bitmap context you would do something like this (I'm writing this code from memory, so there might be some mistakes):

```
// theContext could be
// UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
// or the bmpCtx

CGContextAddPath(theContext, yourCGPath);
CGContextClip(theContext);

// not sure you need the translate and scale...
CGContextTranslateCTM(theContext, 0, bmpHeight);
CGContextScaleCTM(theContext, 1, -1);

CGContextDrawImage(theContext, rect, yourUIImage.CGImage);
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. My image only appears over where the path is, instead of the region that the path goes around.